# Disable Firefox Updates Ubuntu Server

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, firefox

Ok so we downgraded Firefox 47 to previous stable version. BUT firefox keeps updating everyday to 47! Is there any way to completely stop firefox updates in Ubuntu server 14.04 (without GUI,only terminal) ?

We need versions <47 because Selenium has issues with Firefox version 47

Already Tried:
    nano /usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref/channel-prefs.js
    nano /usr/lib/firefox/browser/defaults/preferences/nano syspref.js
    nano /usr/lib/firefox/browser/defaults/preferences/user.js

commented out this: //pref("app.update.channel", "release"); and entered the following: pref("app.update.enabled", false); pref("app.update.silent", false);

I also created a profile folder in ~/.mozilla and added a text files with these: // turn off application updates: user_pref("app.update.enabled", false);

I also tried to block mozilla.org from iptables but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Hold firefox:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep firefox
firefox                                         install
firefox-locale-en                               install
firefox-locale-es                               install
unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks                    install

[13:17:03][root@robert]
[~]
$ echo firefox hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections

[13:17:20][root@robert]
[~]
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep firefox
firefox                                         hold
firefox-locale-en                               install
firefox-locale-es                               install
unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks                    install
```

And to unhold:

```
[13:17:24][root@robert]
[~]
$ sudo apt-mark unhold firefox
Canceled hold on firefox.

[13:17:34][root@robert]
[~]
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep firefox
firefox                                         install
firefox-locale-en                               install
firefox-locale-es                               install
unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks                    install
```

Comment: Why have not you held `firefox-locale-en & firefox-locale-es` also?

Comment: No particular reason. Newer language packs are backwards compatible anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If your firefox is installed via dpkg or apt, you can do this:

```
echo "firefox hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

then verify the hold with :

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

And then you can try to update firefox with apt, normally it won't.

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: It's not :) i wrote it at the same time >< your answer is also more detailed.